# Error installing cordova-plugin-inappbrowser: "Error: Expected "*/" or [^*] but "*" found"

Tags: cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-4

When running

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

I always get the following errors:

```
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@~1.2.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" for ios
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-inappbrowser':undefined
Error: Expected "*/" or [^*] but "*" found.
```

Many of the infos I found are far outdated. I have:

```
corvoda-cli@6.0.0
cordova-ios@4.0.1
```

Comment: Just tried in cordova-cli@6.1.0, cordova-ios@4.0.1 and works fine. Could you try updating cordova?

Comment: Unfortunately I use http://www.macincloud.com/ to build to app, so I can not update the cordova-cli :(
Also on a fresh project it installs without an error. Any clue what the error means? That does it check for?

Comment: did u try to write:  cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

Comment: @ErayBalkanli yes, I tried that too. Same error arises also ...

Comment: Could you please also try: cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Comment: just ried that, same error still

Comment: if this doesnt work, some people advising to use version 5.3.3, so please try. The codes for it: npm uninstall cordova -g ||||
npm install -g cordova@5.3.3 |||| Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli prints out `Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-inappbrowser':undefined
undefined` with cordova@5.3.3

Comment: @GameScripting Could you check if inappbrowser plugin folder available in npm-cache is corrupted by any chance? In windows, i could find the folders under "AppData/Roaming\npm-cache\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" In my case, since i installed 2 versions of inappbrowser plugin, i could see folders (1.2.1& 1.3.0)

Comment: are you using the ionic framework?

Comment: yes, I am using ionic.

Comment: @GameScripting did my answer seem to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few different ways you can go about fixing your issue:

**1.  Check if everything is generating as it should and clean your project.**

---

Sometimes by logging things and looking at output package you can  find that plugin installation is not always reliable. In some cases a couple of plugins might fail to install properly (where you see a "not defined" messages and possibly your `undefined` message in your logs). Usually removing and (re)adding the failing plugin can fix this issue. Another thing to try is cleaning the project before doing a build - both iOS and Android have a cleanup script available in either `./platforms/ios/cordova/clean` and `./platforms/android/cordova/clean` respectively which can help sometimes when run between builds.

You can get these bad/incomplete installs sometimes if you have a bad wifi connection. You can test this by checking you the folders thenselves and the `plugins/fetch.json`,`plugins/ios.json` and `plugins/android.json` files.

Your  `plugins/fetch.json` should look like this:

```
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {
    "source": {
        "type": "registry",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@~1.3.0" //or whatever version
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
    "variables": {}
},
```

When you run `cordova build` or `cordova prepare` it should autogenorate a `.json` for each platform you project has so if you have android and ios it sould create a `android.json` & `ios.json` and that should look like this:

```
"installed_plugins": {
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.example.hello"
        },
```

here try removing the projects build then build it again

```
 rm -rf platforms/ios/build && cordova build ios
```

Now test your project, if no luck try some of the following steps.

**2. Remove and (re)add your projects `platforms` and `plugins` folders.**

---

in base of your apps folder run

```
    rm -rf plugins/ && rm -rf platforms/
    cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
    cordova platform add ios
    cordova run ios
```

Now test your project if not try steps 3 & 4

**3. Test if running `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` will work correctly when in a new project**

---

Try running:

```
     cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
     cd hello
     cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
     cordova platform add ios
     cordova build
```

If it installed into the new project correctly go into  the `plugins/` folder then drag and drop the `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` plugin folder into your current projects `plugins/` folder then test your project again, if your still having an issue double check the make sure the `fetch.json` or `ios.json` / `android.json` files are genorating correctly and they look something like what's in #1.

Also assuming the plugin works in your new app and the new app is using the same app name and package name (when you ran `cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"`) you can also simply replace your current `www/` in the new project and run it and you shouldn't run into any problems. 

**4. Similar to step #3, download the plugin not using the `cli` then add it to your project**

---

Try downloading the .zip file for the plugin here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and add it to your `plugins` folder then test your project

**5. Update your project and cli**

---

Try to be on the current 4.1.0 for ios so in your project folder try running

```
rm -rf plugins/ && rm -rf platforms/ && cordova platform add ios
cordova platforms update cordova-ios@4.1.0
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova run ios --device
```

You can also change your projects version (`cordova-ios` or `cordova-android`) versions by specifying in your `platforms/platforms.json`

e.i.

```
{
    "ios": "4.1.0"
"android": [version number]
}
```

Although it is the current version and will hopefully be issue free I have ran into a plugin issue with this where I am currently using a lower version, so if you are still having issues try again with with version `@4.0.0` or `@3.6.3` 
you can do so with some of the other useful commands I have provided under #6

**6.Make sure you have the right permissions**

---

There is also a chance you could be having a cordova permissions issue so try checking or changing the following locations

run:

```
whoami
```

to find your user name, use that name here:

```
sudo chown -R [add your username here] /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
```

ie

```
sudo chown -R bobsagit /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova


sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/[bobsagit]/.config/
sudo chmod -R 777 ./platforms/ios/
```

and your project folder, assuming its on the desktop and named ExampleProject

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Desktop/ExampleProject/platforms/ios
```

---

**Other Useful commands**

in your apps root folder you can try some of the following 
to see the plugins in your current project

```
cordova plugins list
```

to check what platforms version in you current project run

```
cordova platform list
```

or

```
 cordova platform version
```

It will give you the following output

```
Installed platforms: android 3.5.1, ios 3.5.0
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos
```

check the current platform version of a cordova app

```
cordova platform version ios
```

to update your existing version

```
cordova platform update ios
```

to change projects version first install globally with the version you'd like then add it to your project

```
sudo npm install -g cordova-ios@4.1.0
cordova platform add ios@4.1.0
```

or to update to a specify a specific version

```
cordova platform update ios@4.1.0
```

---

to see the currently running cordova version on your machine run

```
cordova --version
```

for more detail run

```
npm info cordova
```

**Addition notes:** 
When you add `cordova` plugins they are plugins meant for the device and not the browser so make sure you testing on a device by appending --device to your run command like so
`cordova run ios --device`

 The old cli you would add plugin with a `.` syntax  ie `org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` now you don't, so make sure you are using `-`'s like you where doing `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

**UPDATE:** I just read your comment where you said it it works in a different project. I don't know much about http://www.macincloud.com/ but it looks like your problem is an issue from the initial install of the plugin so try cleaning it or remove and adding it back like in step 1 and 2

Comment: "Also assuming the plugin works in your new app and the new app is using the same app name and package name (when you ran cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld") you can also simply replace your current www/ in the new project and run it and you shouldn't run into any problems." - This is what I finally did and what worked.

Comment: Good! Sorry I've been logged into my other account and just saw your other comment. But yes, you're correct, sometimes the plugin will create a  `plugins/fetch.json` that tells your  `ios.json` (or `android.json`) files what tell your build that you have the plugins installed that aren't because there was an interuption during your install like a spotty internet connection that genorated the json you see in in my #1, telling your build you have `plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` when you may not or have a complete version.

Comment: If you run into another plugin issue still read through my answer again because there is a lot of info there. Also remember any plugin you install using the `cordova plugin add` or `ionic plugin add` are plugins are to set how they interact on an actual device or emulate that sets/configures permissions for it to run on a devices OS

Answer (score 1):

Update the `node.js` and `npm`, create the separate project install platform and plugins paste your www folder into that. Same thing happened to me I did the same, after updating `node.js`and`npm` resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@GameScripting, if the plugin installs without error on a new project (as you mentioned in a comment), then it should not be an issue with the npm cache or the cordova version.

When I encountered issues adding or removing plugins in the past, it was always related to a corrupt platform plugin json file. These are in a folder called plugins in your app folder. Each platform has its own. I believe you're doing iOS development, so look at the ios.json file in that folder.

First inspect the json in plugins\ios.json to make sure it's well formed (you can compare with a working project, for example, or see the below file). Next, if there's a reference to the  cordova-plugin-inappbrowser anywhere, remove the entry, then retry the command:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

```
{
    "prepare_queue": {
        "installed": [],
        "uninstalled": []
    },
    "config_munge": {
        "files": {}
    },
    "installed_plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-device": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>"
        },
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>"
        }        
    },
    "dependent_plugins": {}
}
```